# TypeScript automatically `as const` my type which cause error

Tags: typescript

Please see the following typescript code:

```
type Interpolation = null | undefined | boolean | number | string;

type DefaultTheme = {
    color: {
        primary: {
            active: string;
            default: string;
            hover: string;
            disabled: string;
            background: string;
        };
        secondary: {
            active: string;
            default: string;
            hover: string;
            disabled: string;
            background: string;
        };
    };
};

type Classes<K extends string> = {
    [className in K]: string;
};

type Theme = DefaultTheme & {
    [key: string]: any;
};

type DynamicStyle<K extends string> = (
    theme: Theme,
    deps: any[],
    classes: Classes<K>,
) => Interpolation;

type Style<K extends string> = string | DynamicStyle<K>;

type Styles<K extends string> = ReadonlyArray<readonly [K, Style<K>]>;

function makeStyles<K extends string>(styles: Styles<K>) {
    return styles;
}

makeStyles([
    [
        'tag',
        (theme, [a, b, c]) => {
            return '';
        },
    ],
    ['label', ''],
]);
```

This will cause error

> Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"tag"'.

Notice the tag is `'"tag"'`, which I think typescript `as const` my type.

I want it to be string, not `'"tag"'`.

Is there any way to force it to be a string?

I think typescript will automatically widen it to be string, I don't know why the behavior is different here.

[image]
[image]

And here is my tsconfig, and my typescript version is `^3.6.4`

```
{
  "include": ["src", "types", "test"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "esnext",
    "lib": ["dom", "esnext"],
    "importHelpers": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "rootDir": "./",
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["src/*", "node_modules/*"]
    },
    "jsx": "react",
    "esModuleInterop": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know the problem, because this line `ReadonlyArray<readonly [K, Style<K>]>`

Which seems narrowed down my type